# Problemas con Div al recargar jquery

Tags: jquery

Mi problema es sencillo, la solución no para mi.

Tengo en mi JS una operación la cual hago:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.botonEliminar').click(function (e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   var fila = $(this).parents('tr');
   var id = fila.data('id');

   var form = $('#form-delete');

   var url = form.attr('action').replace(':user_id', id);

   var data = form.serialize();

   $.post(url,data, function (respuesta) {
       //alert(respuesta);
       //fila.fadeOut();



       location.reload();

   }). fail(function () {
       alert('No se pudo eliminar el usuario');
   });  }); });
```

En fin, lo que quiero es que no haga el location.reload(); Por lo tanto, lo que necesito es que el div que hago la validación se refresque sin hacerlo toda la pagina.

```
$("#container").load("/");
```

En esa lo que hago es refrescar el DIV pero a la vez me inserta la pagina de inicio la cual solo quiero refrescar ese DIV.

¿Que me aconsejan?

Uso: Laravel 5.3
Jquery 2.1.3

En fin, el Laravel me funciona bien el problema es el DIV y la ejecución mía.

Comment: Para no tener que refrescar las páginas te recomiendo usar funciones AJAX.

Comment: Bueno en este caso uso Jquery, que es lo que mejor manejo, en ese caso... ¿Que me recomendarías para ese caso?. @Error404

Comment: AJAX también se basa en Javascript. Creo que desde Javascript y JQuery  no se puede.

Comment: ¿Lo recomendable seria congelar la pagina, decir que fue exitosa la operación, la pongo a segundos y luego que refresque? @Error404

Comment: Nunca se debería de bloquear la página en una ejecución. Por eso te recomendé usar AJAX, porque a la vez que tu puedes seguir navegando por la página, AJAX trabaja en segundo plano.

Comment: No logro entender muy bien Ajax y por eso acudí a Jquery, a ver... Y si con Jquery se pone un setInterval(); ¿Se refrescaría la pagina igual? Nunca lo he intentado pero según leo y leo, recomiendan ese; O... Como se haría lo de arriba pero con Ajax? @Error404

Comment: Ya estás usando ajax con la función `post()`, solo tienes que decirle en que `div` quieres que cargue los datos que traes.

Comment: Ya lo hice y ya lo puse a funcionar pero al refrescar el div se pierde la funcionalidad del boton eliminar en los otros "usuarios" que tengo, me toca reiniciar la pagina para hacerlo funcionar. @Error404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo remueve la linea del reload; si necesitas mostrar alguna información en el div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.botonEliminar').click(function (e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   var fila = $(this).parents('tr');
   var id = fila.data('id');

   var form = $('#form-delete');

   var url = form.attr('action').replace(':user_id', id);

   var data = form.serialize();

   $.post(url,data, function (respuesta) {
       //alert(respuesta);
       //fila.fadeOut();

$("#container").html('<h2>Guardado con éxito</h2>');

   }). fail(function () {
       alert('No se pudo eliminar el usuario');
   });  }); });
```

si lo que quieres mostrar son los datos, que devuelve el insert, entonces esos datos deben venir en la variable response, preferiblemente en json

Comment: Si tienes razon, pero ya no me funciona de nuevo las acciones como click al refrescar el div... @Aquiles Perez

Comment: Cual es el fin de tu función? , me imagino que es algo como un botón eliminar, que dependiendo de la respuesta muestre error o una notificación que diga eliminado con éxito, luego de eso ocultar el elemento eliminado o algo asi?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.botonEliminar').click(function (e) {
  //bloqueas el boton y evitas hacer submits mientras esta procesando
  $('.botonEliminar').prop('disabled', true);

  e.preventDefault();
  var fila = $(this).parents('tr');
  var id = fila.data('id');
  var form = $('#form-delete');
  var url = form.attr('action').replace(':user_id', id);
  var data = form.serialize();

  $.post(url,data, function (respuesta) {
   // si la respuesta es el texto que quieres mostrar, 
   // si es json o cualquier cosa pues respuesta.mensaje... 
   // Lo que tengas, eso depende de tu tipo de respuesta
   $('#div_respuesta').html(respuesta); 

   // si quieres añadir y no cargarte lo que tiene ese div, 
   // o el elemento que sea, no tiene por que ser div.
   // o bien si recorres un array y quieres mostrar toda la info 
   // de ese array en un div
   $('#div_respuesta_append').append(respuesta);


  }). fail(function () {
    $('#div_respuesta').html("no se pudo modificar el usuario"); 
    // me ahorro un alert
  }).always(function() {
    // vuelvo a poner el boton activo, ya sea success o fail
    $('.botonEliminar').prop('disabled', false);
  });
}); 
});
```

Prueba a ver

Comment: ¿Si quiero recargar una pagina? Por ejemplo en ella tengo el botonEliminar o el botonActivar, bueno si presiono botonEliminar me refresca el div pero ya no funciona el boton, refresco la pagina y en efecto me funciono pero vuelvo a ejercutar esta vez el activar ahora el desactivar no funciona... @Mikel

Comment: Explicate mejor, no entiendo que quieres decir. Flujo de eventos?

Comment: A ver, yo recargo el div, en el esta el botonEliminar, y elimina y me recarga correctamente sin actualizar la pagina... Pero ya no funciona de nuevo el boton. @Mikel

Comment: pero por que no funciona, por que el boton esta dentro del div_respuesta? O se ve todavía gris? o no se ve gris pero no hace nada?. Entiendo que si lo has eliminado ya no puedes eliminarlo de nuevo. A eso me refiero. Si esta dentro del div respuesta, sacalo de ahi, si se queda en gris prueba a poner `$('.botonEliminar').prop('disabled', false);` en el `success` para probar, por que, el `always` debería ejecutarse tanto en el fail como en el success

Comment: El problema es el siguiente: Le doy desactivar y este me desactiva el registro y me refresca el div: [imagen1](http://imgur.com/a/X9zjk)  hay le presiono y me sale esto sin recargar la pagina de forma excelente: [imagen2] (http://imgur.com/AhYhciE) pero ya no me funciona el resto si le doy activar o a los otros desactivar xd @Mikel1

Comment: vale algún cambio: https://jsfiddle.net/zgymkshf/2/ (bloquear solo el boton correspondiente). El fallo que dices creo que es por que tienes un error de javascript, que código tienes ahora?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/puzhej08/ Lo que mostre en la imagen es que si desactiva bien, recarga y muestra el boton activar y si le da clic activar pues aparece el boton desactivar, PERO cuando recarga el div por ambos lados ya deja de funcionar el JS solo tengo esos dos... Obvio en eso no funciona pero es para que los veas. @Mikel

Comment: Con esa parte no puedo saberlo... De todas formas, pregunto, al hacer el post para que cargas el formularioPrincipal y el js/codigo.js? Y si redireccionas directamente? o si en la respuesta del post devuelves los campos?

Comment: Recarga una pagina, la que muestra el formulario xd pero los botones dejan de funcionar

Comment: Prueba a poner el $('.botonEliminar').prop('disabled', false); antes de cargarlos

Comment: Ya lo puse y no funciono, en fin... Lo que haré sera probar nuevas cosas, igual ya le puse valido porque funciono correctamente lo que pusiste, muchas gracias.

Comment: Oh lo siento xD mira la solucion fue mas sencilla haha y la tenia hay... $('#principal').load(location.href +'#principal'); el id #principal es mi div que contiene esa tabla que mostre en la imagen, con ella simplemente hacia el cargar pero... perdia todo el DOM, si refrescaba pero hasta hay... Luego con eso puedo volver a usar los botones y no se pierden los atributos, o sea refresca si pero no me recarga la pagina. Lloro de felicidad ;_; espero te sirva xD igual MUCHAS GRACIAS por todo.